# ¿Como puedo comunicar un Activity con un adapter que se encuentra en otro Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, adapter

Tengo un adaptador dentro de un fragmento que pertenece a una Actividad A, desde este adaptador abro el detalle de un elemento en una Actividad B. ¿Cómo puedo decirle al adaptador de la Actividad A que tiene que actualizar la lista del adaptador que está en un fragmento de la Actividad B?

Este es el método que tengo dentro de la actividad:

```kotlin
private fun setOnClickFavoriteListener(recipe: RecipesItem?) {
        binding?.recipeDetailContainerFavoriteButton?.setOnClickListener {
            if (recipe?.isFavorite == true) {
                isFavorite = false
                viewModel.setFavoriteRecipe(recipe.id, isFavorite)
                binding?.recipeDetailImgFavoriteButton?.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.silver
                    )
                )
            } else {
                isFavorite = true
                viewModel.setFavoriteRecipe(recipe?.id, isFavorite)
                binding?.recipeDetailImgFavoriteButton?.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.sunglo
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Y este es mi adaptador que no está en la misma actividad, por lo que no tengo comunicación entre ellos:

```kotlin
class FavoritesAdapter(private val favorites: List<RecipesItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FavoritesViewHolder {
        val binding = FavoritesRowBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return FavoritesViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FavoritesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(favorites[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return favorites.size
    }
}

class FavoritesViewHolder(private val binding: FavoritesRowBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(recipesItem: RecipesItem) {
        binding.favoritesRowImgRecipeImage.load(recipesItem.imageURL)
        binding.favoritesRowLabelRecipeName.text = recipesItem.name
        binding.favoritesRowLabelTime.text = binding.root.context.getString(
            R.string.recipe_time,
            recipesItem.time
        )
        binding.favoritesRowLabelDifficult.text = recipesItem.difficult
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val bundle = bundleOf(RECIPE_BUNDLE to recipesItem)
            val intent = Intent(binding.root.context, RecipeDetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtras(bundle)
            binding.root.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Intenté poner la obtención de la lista de favoritos en el onResume, pero hace un efecto extraño donde muestra brevemente la imagen de la lista vacía y luego muestra la lista actualizada:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FavoritesFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: FavoritesViewModel by viewModels()
    private var binding: FragmentFavoritesBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentFavoritesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (activity as DashboardActivity).showToolbar(true)
        (activity as DashboardActivity).setToolbarTitle(getString(R.string.option_menu_favorite))
    }

    private fun initObservers() {
        viewModel.favoritesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { favorites ->
            if (favorites.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.hide()
                binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.show()

            } else {
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.show()
                binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.hide()
                val adapter = FavoritesAdapter(favorites)
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                    context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false
                )
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.adapter = adapter
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.getFavoritesFromDatabase()
        initObservers()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        binding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema con la animacion, es que estas creando y poniendo el adaptador al RecyclerView cada que regresas a la actividad.

Lo mejor y mas sencillo, es crear dentro del adaptador, una lista que este siendo observada y manejada por DiffUtil, ya que se encargará de actualizar la lista con el nuevo contenido, y te dará incluso las animaciones necesarias, puedes crear una extension de DiffUtil para esto de la siguiente manera.

```
fun <VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, T> RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>.basicDiffUtil(
    initialList: List<T> = emptyList(),
    areItemsTheSame: (T, T) -> Boolean = { old, new -> old == new },
    areContentsTheSame: (T, T) -> Boolean = { old, new -> old == new },
) =
    Delegates.observable(initialList) { _, old, new ->
        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = old.size

            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = new.size

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                areItemsTheSame(old[oldItemPosition], new[newItemPosition])

            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItemPosition: Int,
                newItemPosition: Int,
            ): Boolean =
                areContentsTheSame(old[oldItemPosition], new[newItemPosition])

        }).dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
```

Con esto, solamente creas una variable lista dentro de tu adaptador, en lugar de pasarle una por parametro.

```
class FavoritesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesViewHolder>() {

    var favorites: List<RecipesItem> by basicDiffUtil({old,new->old.id == new.id})

}
```

De tu metodo initObservers(), vas a mover las siguientes lineas al onViewCreated:

```
adapter = FavoritesAdapter()
binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.adapter = adapter
```

El adaptador tiene que ser global, por lo que lo declaras:

```
private var binding: FragmentFavoritesBinding? = null
private lateinir var adapter: FavoritesAdapter
```

Te va a quedar asi, ya solo actualizar el adaptador con la nueva lista.

```
private fun initObservers() {
    viewModel.favoritesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { favorites ->
        if (favorites.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.hide()
            binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.show()

        } else {
            binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.show()
            binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.hide()
            adapter.list = favorites
        }

    }
}
```